# Illustrator pressure brush only works after pressing hard

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've got a new wacom tablet (Intuos medium) with the default pen and a copy of Illustrator CC 2015.  I'm trying to set up pressure-sensitive brushes.

I have a simple brush with the size set to be pressure sensitive:

[image]

I then try to use this by pressing very lightly– I get a big fat line.  I Try again and press heavily- I get a line that is maybe 10% fatter.  I try a final time: pressing very heavily, *then* very lightly.  *Now* I get the expected result: super fat followed by super thin.

[image]

Note that, for both instances of 'soft', I'm pressing as soft as I physically can, yet I'm getting two very different line widths.  Any idea what's causing this?  Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Look at the Wacom system control panel to set up touch-sensitivity curves [long time since I used one, so idk exactly where in it to look]

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the sensitivity curve (I have tried playing with that already).  The issue is that the same pressure produces different results at different times.  For reference, the pressure sensitivity works fine in Photoshop.